# How to add an "Else" statement to this php. I ve tried for 3 days now

Tags: php, input, directory

I'm working on a project where you type in a text input box named "q" and the info is forwarded to the PHP file where it will find in the directory the exact file name (in this case a .htm page). Currently, that works. What I've been trying to do all night though is two things.

1) I would like the form to show only exact matches instead of anything with matching letters or numbers. 2) I would like to add an "else" statement so if nothing is found it displays another line of text entirely. Any help pointing me in the right direction or showing me what I'm doing wrong would greatly help.

PS. My goal is to also implement a drop-down box next to the search input box so it will go to a subdirectory when searched with the drop-down box. For example:

Search Term = "Folder" &  Dropdown Box = "Sub Folder within main Folder"

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
<input name="q" type="text"> 
<input type="submit"></form>

<?php
$dir = 'folder';
$exclude = array('*'); 
$q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtoupper($_GET['q']) : ''; 
$res = opendir($dir); 
while(false!== ($file = readdir($res)))
if(strpos(strtoupper($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) { 
echo "<a href='$dir/$file'>$file</a>";}
closedir($res);
?>
```

**Update:**

New code ive scrapped together. It is still not doing exactly what im looking for. Right now, I have a form that sends a text box and drop down file to my PHP code. The textbox works fine but the drop down doesn't send info over. The array constantly shows only the last result of "WY". Here is my code.

```
<form action="search.php" method="get">
<input name="q" type="text"> 

<select name="states" id="states">
<option value="CA">CA</option>
<option value="NV">NV</option>
<option value="TX">TX</option>
<option value="WY">WY</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php
$dir = 'folder';
$_POST['states'];
$states = array("CA", "NV", "TX", "WY");
foreach($states as $state);
$q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtoupper($_GET['q']) : ''; 
$res = opendir($dir); 
while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) {
    if(strpos(strtoupper($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file)) {
        echo "<a href='$dir/$file'>$file</a>";
    }
}

closedir($res);
?>

<?php
 echo $htmlHeader;
 while($stuff){
 echo $stuff;
 }
 echo "<script>window.location = 
 'http://www.example.com/$dir/$state/$q.htm'</script>";
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be all you need:

Basicly what you want to do is find the closing bracelet for the if clause, and write an `else {}` behind this

```
    <?php
    $dir = 'folder';
    $exclude = array('*'); 
    $q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtoupper($_GET['q']) : ''; 
    $res = opendir($dir); 
    while(false!== ($file = readdir($res)))
        if(strpos(strtoupper($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) {
            echo "<a href='$dir/$file'>$file</a>";
        } else {
            ...
        }
    closedir($res);
    ?>
```

Though it would be highly recommendable to wrap the statements inside the while in braces too:

```
    <?php
    $dir = 'folder';
    $exclude = array('*'); 
    $q = (isset($_GET['q']))? strtoupper($_GET['q']) : ''; 
    $res = opendir($dir); 
    while(false!== ($file = readdir($res))) {
        if(strpos(strtoupper($file),$q)!== false &&!in_array($file,$exclude)) {
            echo "<a href='$dir/$file'>$file</a>";
        } else {
            ...
        }
    }

    closedir($res);
    ?>
```

Comment: First off, thank you for getting back to me to quickly. So i set the else to echo "hi" and i get the oddest result. It seems like the word "hi" repeats itself whether or not it finds a match or not. Its the same result i was getting as before and im not sure why? See attached image for reference 
http://www.imgur.com/k4W1Kve

Comment: hi gets outputted everytime there is no match, in your case 4 times

Comment: Im not very well versed in PHP. Where is it saying to repeat 4 times? So i can take it out.

Comment: well you execute this in a while loop, so I guess readdir outputs 5 directories, 1 match and 4 non-matches (which output hi)